# Spring Security dedicated SecurityFilterChain for child context not called

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot application with Spring Security and multiple child web context.
I want to have a general `SecurityFilterChain` in the parent context, and a dedicated, more specialized `SecurityFilterChain` in the child context, that is only applied to requests concerning the child context.

A minimal example has these classes:

*SpringMultipleSecurityApplication.java*

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringMultipleSecurityApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringMultipleSecurityApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

*ParentConfig*

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ParentConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .securityMatcher("/parent/**")
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.anyRequest().permitAll());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    ServletRegistrationBean<DispatcherServlet> childServlet(ServletContext context) {
        String regionConnectorName = "MyChild";
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.setId(regionConnectorName);
        applicationContext.register(ChildConfig.class);
        applicationContext.setServletContext(context);
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(applicationContext);

        ServletRegistrationBean<DispatcherServlet> connectorServletBean = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(dispatcherServlet, "/foo/*");
        connectorServletBean.setName(regionConnectorName);
        connectorServletBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);

        return connectorServletBean;
    }
}
```

*ParentController*

```
@RestController
public class ParentController {
    @GetMapping("/parent/foo")
    public String lib() {
        return "This is /parent/foo";
    }
}
```

*ChildConfig*

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableWebSecurity
@SpringBootApplication
public class ChildConfig {
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .securityMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/foo/child/**"))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.anyRequest().permitAll());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

*ChildController*

```
@RestController
public class ChildController {
    @GetMapping("/child/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello from child";
    }
}
```

These are just minimal configurations, I intend to configure e.g. an oauth2Login in the *ChildConfig's SecurityFilterChain.*

When starting the application I see that both filter chains are registered:

```
DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure Or [Mvc [pattern='/parent/**']] with [...
DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure Ant [pattern='/foo/child/**'] with [...
```

However, when making a request *to /foo/child/hello* the log output shows that the chain from the child context is not called:

```
FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Or [Mvc [pattern='/parent/**']]...
FilterChainProxy        : No security for GET /foo/child/hello
```

A request to */parent/foo* results in the filter chain being executed.

How can I configure a `SecurityFilterChain` in a child context, and make sure that it is applied to requests that should be handled by the child `DispatcherServlet` (i.e. */foo* in the example).
Is it even possible to configure a filter chain in a child context or do all the security filter chains have to be registered in the parent?

I tried having multiple `SecurityFilterChain` in the parent, and it works, however, my security chain in the child context is more complex and depends on some beans of the child context, so I don't want to put the whole config into the parent.

I manged to create a `Filter` Bean in the child context and register it in the parent so that it is called for requests by using a `DelegatingFilterProxy`. However, it's only possible to delegate to a `Filter` and not a `SecurityFilterChain`, which is what I need to be able to use e.g. oauth2Login on the `HttpSecurity` object.

The JavaDoc for `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` mentions that one can override `getDispatcherWebApplicationContextSuffix` to return the name of a WebApplicationContext where the `DelegatingFilterProxy` should be searched, but I have not gotten this to work, the `getDispatcherWebApplicationContextSuffix` is never called.